# why does my program gets terminated after i insert the first element?

Tags: c, linked-list

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include "node2.h"

void create();

int main(){

    create();
    return 0;
}

void create(){

    int n, num;
    printf("How many nodes do you want to create?\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while(n <= 0){
        printf("Please enter a number greater than 0 or '-1' to exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if(n == -1) exit(1);
    }

    struct node *head = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node)), *temp;
    if(head = NULL) printf("Memory cannot be allocated");


    printf("Enter the elements you want to store\n");
    printf("Element at node 1: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    head -> data = num;
    head -> link = NULL;
    temp = head;

    for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++){
        struct node *current = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        printf("Element at node %d: ", i + 2);
        scanf("%d", &num);

        current -> data = num;
        current -> link = NULL;
        temp -> link = current;
        temp = current;
    }

    return;
}
```

when i run this code the program doesn't go past scanf("%d", &num); this always happens to me when i forget the & symbol in scanf but this isn't the case in this example. so why does it get teminated?

Comment: `if(head = NULL)` ==> `if (head == NULL)` ... and **turn on and mind your compiler warnings**.

Comment: In C when you declare a function without arguments, you need to specify `void`. The declaration `void create();` declares `create` as a function taking an unspecified number of arguments of unspecified type.

Answer (score 1):

The condition placed in the while loop ie.. while(n<=0) is illogical. It should be while (n>=0)
The code will not  iterate not even ones. This is a kind of logical error.